# How to properly capture zap logger output in unit tests

Tags: go, logging, go-zap

Based off the configurations for `zap.NewDevelopmentConfig()` and `zap.NewProductionConfig()`, I've assumed that zap writes logs to `stderr`. However, I can't seem to capture the output in unit tests.

I have the following `captureOutput` func:

```
func captureOutput(f func()) string {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stdout := os.Stdout
    os.Stdout = w
    defer func() {
        os.Stdout = stdout
    }()

    stderr := os.Stderr
    os.Stderr = w
    defer func() {
        os.Stderr = stderr
    }()

    f()
    w.Close()

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    io.Copy(&buf, r)

    return buf.String()
}
```

It fails to capture zap output but does manage to grab output from `fmt.Println(...)`:

```
func TestZapCapture(t *testing.T) {
    auditor, _ := zap.NewProduction()
    output := captureOutput(func() {
        auditor.Info("hi")
    })

    assert.NotEmpty(t, output)
    //fails to captures output
}

func TestFmtCapture(t *testing.T) {
    output := captureOutput(func() {
        fmt.Println("hi")
    })

    assert.NotEmpty(t, output)
    //successfully captures output
}
```

I'm aware of using the zap observer for situations like this but my real use case is to test a highly modified zap logger so testing a new `zap.Core` would defeat the purpose. Whats the best way to capture that output?

Comment: Related (though not what you want) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734529/how-to-test-logging-of-a-zap-logger-built-from-custom-config

Comment: Your answer below definitely would work but required modifying the existing core. And while similar, I decided to extract the config from my constructor function in order to leverage an in-memory zap sink instead (from the link you posted): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737940/5042150

Comment: note that only the second solution requires modifying the existing core. it depends on what you want to test. Using the custom sink is also a fine option

Comment: If you just want to see the zap logs during `go test -v`, simply use `zap.ReplaceGlobals(zaptest.NewLogger(t))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Test that messages are logged at all

Use `zapcore.NewTee`. In your unit tests, you instantiate a logger whose core is comprised of your own highly modified core and the observed core tee'd together. The observed core will receive the log [entries](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore#Entry), so you can assert that single fields are what you expect (level, message, fields, etc.)

```
func main() {
    // some arbitrary custom core logger
    mycore := zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        os.Stderr,
        zapcore.InfoLevel,
    )
    // test core
    observed, logs := observer.New(zapcore.InfoLevel)
    
    // new logger with the two cores tee'd together
    logger := zap.New(zapcore.NewTee(mycore, observed))

    logger.Error("foo")

    entry := logs.All()[0]
    fmt.Println(entry.Message == "foo")            // true
    fmt.Println(entry.Level == zapcore.ErrorLevel) // true
}
```

##### Test the final log format

In this case you want to pipe the logger output to arbitrary writers. You can achieve this with [`zap.CombineWriteSyncers`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#CombineWriteSyncers) and inject this as a dependency of your custom core.

```
// this would be placed in your main code
func NewCustomLogger(pipeTo io.Writer) zapcore.Core {
    return zapcore.NewCore(
        zapcore.NewJSONEncoder(zap.NewProductionEncoderConfig()),
        zap.CombineWriteSyncers(os.Stderr, zapcore.AddSync(pipeTo)),
        zapcore.InfoLevel,
    )
}

func TestLogger(t *testing.T) {
    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    // call the constructor from your test code with the arbitrary writer
    mycore := NewCustomLogger(b)

    logger := zap.New(mycore)
    logger.Error("foo")

    fmt.Println(b.String()) // {"level":"error","ts":1639813360.853494,"msg":"foo"}
}
```