# Capture zap logger output when I can't alter the way logger created

Tags: go, go-zap

I need to write unit tests for Zap logger, to check it's output. There're a plenty tutorials in the internet how to capture zap log output but they suppose that I can create logger with custom X, Y, Z... In my case I receive logger object that I can't change anything in a way it initiated, and it prints logs to stdout. How can I still check output of this logger?

Some code for reference:

I create logger by following code. Once again, it's a wrapper and I need to test its behavior, so I can't change it.

```golang
logger, err := NewCustomLogger(context.Background(), zapcore.DebugLevel, "unit tests")
if err != nil {
    assert.Fail(s.T(), "couldn't initialize logger")
    return
}
```

I can't change `NewCustomLogger` and it returns `*zap.Logger`, is there any workaround that I can use?

P.S. I tried to use this answer and catch stdout, but it didn't work for me:

[In Go, how do I capture stdout of a function into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473800/in-go-how-do-i-capture-stdout-of-a-function-into-a-string)

```golang
old := os.Stdout // keep backup of the real stdout
    r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
    os.Stdout = w

    logger.Warn("This log will be intercepted")

    outC := make(chan string)
    // copy the output in a separate goroutine so printing can't block indefinitely
    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        outC <- buf.String()
    }()

    // back to normal state
    w.Close()
    os.Stdout = old // restoring the real stdout
    out := <-outC

    // reading our temp stdout
    fmt.Println("previous output:")
    fmt.Print(out)
```

`fmt.Print(out)` prints empty string string.

P.P.S.

I tried this answer too and it partially worked: [How to properly capture zap logger output in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70400426/how-to-properly-capture-zap-logger-output-in-unit-tests?rq=2)

```golang
logger, err := NewLogger(context.Background(), zapcore.DebugLevel, "unit tests")
    if err != nil {
        assert.Fail(s.T(), "couldn't initialize logger")
        return
    }

    observed, logs := observer.New(zapcore.InfoLevel)
    observedLogger := zap.New(zapcore.NewTee(logger.Core(), observed))

    observedLogger.Warn("This log will be intercepted by the custom core")

    entry := logs.All()[0]

    fmt.Print(entry)
```

But it doesn't print `InitialFields`: https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Config.InitialFields

see `foo_env` field:

```
{"level":"warn","ts":1710415413.844058,"msg":"This log will be intercepted by the custom core","foo_env":"test_env_foo"}
{{warn 2024-03-14 13:23:33.844058 +0200 IST m=+0.003122709  This log will be intercepted by the custom core undefined } []}
```

UPDATE:

The logger created in this way, but as I say I can't change this implementation:

```golang
func NewLogger(level zapcore.Level, serviceName string) (*zap.Logger, error) {
    productionCfg := zap.NewProductionConfig()
    productionCfg.Level = zap.NewAtomicLevelAt(level)
    productionCfg.InitialFields = map[string]interface{}{
        "INITIAL_FIELD":"INITIAL_FIELD_VALUE",  //example, initial fields populated from env variables
    }

    logger, err := productionCfg.Build(zap.AddStacktrace(zap.ErrorLevel))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to build logger")
    }

    logger = logger.Named(serviceName)

    return logger, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route stderr output to a temp file and then read the content of the temp file to get the log output and match it against the expected output.

Example:

```
func TestNewLogger(t *testing.T) {
    // create a temporary file to redirect stderr
    file, err := os.CreateTemp(".", "temp")
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    defer os.Remove(file.Name())
    os.Stderr = file

    // init the logger as normal
    logger, err := NewLogger(zapcore.DebugLevel, "test")
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    logger.Info("test")

    // read the file content for testing
    logOut, err := os.ReadFile(file.Name())
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    assert.Regexp(t, `{"level":"info","ts":.*,"logger":"test","caller":".*","msg":"test","INITIAL_FIELD":"INITIAL_FIELD_VALUE"}`, string(logOut))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on a POSIX system with [the `dup2(2)` system call](https://manpages.debian.org/2/dup2) you can perform direct surgery on the file descriptor underlying the stdout —like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

func mustMakeStdoutLogger() *zap.Logger {
    conf := zap.NewProductionConfig()
    conf.OutputPaths = []string{"stdout"}

    logger, err := conf.Build()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return logger
}

func mustGetSyscallConn(f *os.File) syscall.RawConn {
    rc, err := f.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return rc
}

func main() {
    logger := mustMakeStdoutLogger()
    defer logger.Sync()

    pr, pw, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer pw.Close()

    var pwFD uintptr
    err = mustGetSyscallConn(pw).Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        pwFD = fd
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var dupErr error
    err = mustGetSyscallConn(os.Stdout).Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        dupErr = syscall.Dup2(int(pwFD), int(fd))
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if dupErr != nil {
        panic(dupErr)
    }

    errCh := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(pr)
        defer func() {
            errCh <- scanner.Err()
        }()

        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "!!!", scanner.Text(), "!!!")
        }
    }()

    _, err = fmt.Println("a plain message to stdout")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logger.Info("a test message")
    logger.Sync()

    err = pr.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = <-errCh
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%#v\n", err)
}
```

What happens here is as following:

1. A kernel-provided [`pipe(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/pipe) is created.
2. The file descriptor of its write end is saved.
3. The standard output's file descriptor is atomically replaced with that one using the `dup(2)` system call.
4. Everything written to stdout now goes into the pipe, so we can read that from its read end; this is done in a goroutine (for testing purposes).

Note that in order to make the goroutine quit, we close the write end of the pipe, so the goroutine actually quits with an error.
Unfortunately, the error appears to be useless (in my version of Go at least)—in the sense it cannot be sensibly asserted for its type of value; maybe you could match its error string.

---

Note that

```golang
r, w, _ := os.Pipe()
os.Stdout = w
```

did not work because `os.Stdout` is a mere package-level variable with no magic attached to it.
Supposedly, when a logger instance was being constructed, its initialization code has read the then-current value of `os.Stdout` and saved it somewhere, so when you later rewrote that variable with a new value, that did nothing to the already created logger.

Comment: Hi kostix, thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When I use your created logger it indeed prints and catches output, but my logger's output is invisible for him :(

Comment: @Anatoly, [1/2] my answer supposes the logger is configured to print to stdout—because you said «I tried to use this answer and catch stdout». If that's not true, we need more detals. Say, if it prints to stderr, you need to redirect its FD instead; if it prints to a regular file, this also can be dealt with (a bit more cumbersome and way less stable but still doable). All-in-all, you need to make your requirements more precise.

Comment: [2/2] To see whether the logger prints to stdout or stderr, just run your program while having had redirected stderr or stdout, correspondingly, to `/dev/null`—that is, if `./program >/dev/null` still prints to the console it's likely outputting to stderr; if `./program 2>/dev/null` still prints to the console it's likely outputting to stdout. If `./program >/dev/null 2>&1` _still prints_ to the console, it's way more interesting, and we need the logger setup code to figure out what happens :-)

Comment: I added code that initializes logger and will check what you have mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: @Anatoly, «…added code that initializes logger…»—good! So, let's read [the docs on `NewProductionConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#NewProductionConfig): «Logs are written to standard error.». As you can see in my answer, I explicitly reconfigure that to make the logger write to stdout (as I thought that was your requirement).

Comment: kostix, I really apologize for misleading you. I need to learn this a bit in depth, was sure that by default it's stdout and only errors written to stderr :(

Comment: @Anatoly, «was sure that by default it's stdout and only errors written to stderr»–that was actually a reasonable expectation, but two points 1) The stock logger from the Go's stdlib (`log`) logs to stderr, so `zap` could as well take it as its default to be closer to the "stock" behavour; 2) Where to log is a bit philosophical question: if a program also has "normal" output, it's reasonable to put it to stdout, but then where to put logging? The choice of stderr appears to be reasonable while certainly debatable. (While we're at it: are you up to trying to fix my solution by yourself?)

Comment: Honestly I tried with help of ChatGPT but unsuccessful, it changed the following lines:

```go
err = mustGetSyscallConn(os.Stderr).Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        dupErr = syscall.Dup2(int(pwFD), int(fd))
    })
```

but I get now:  Process finished with the exit code 141 (interrupted by signal 13:SIGPIPE)

I stuck here :(

Comment: «interrupted by signal 13:SIGPIPE»–a process is sent this signal when the reading end of a pipe is closed, so there's no way a [`write(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/write) there could ever succeed. Since my example involves a pipe, I guess you've somehow screwed it while adapting to your needs, so the pipe's read end gets closed before the logger finishes writing into it. «I tried with help of ChatGPT»–I honestly feel uneasy about this: if you intend to ask an LLM instead of trying to read the docs to make sense of what happens in my code, I think I'm not equipped to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Regarding your remark, it's philosophical question, it's completely new field for me and sometimes LLM can be a shortcut in learning path to get it quick and dirty and then learn in depth, but I completely understand you and respect your opinion. Will try to continue to figure out how to solve it. If you can, don't delete yet your answer.

Comment: @Anatoly, I certainly do not intend to delete my answer :-) Actually, if you will come up with an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) of your SIGPIPE problem, feel free to post another question (and put a link to it here).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you want but it seems this functionality is not supported by zap according to this Github Issue:

https://github.com/uber-go/zap/issues/859

To quote prashantv:

```
This is expected because of how zap works:

Cores encode fields as they are added
WrapCore cannot go back, as the previous fields are not stored unencoded
```

As a result the initial fields cannot be unencoded.

Just to take a step back, I would review again why checking the initial fields is important for your tests. In theory your unit test should check the functionality of your unit. Initial Fields coming through the logger shouldn't matter, as it shouldn't affect your unit.